# And the windows showed the day

Tags: meaning

> Till the gale blew off on the marshes
>   And **the windows showed the day**
>   And the Ox and the Ass together
>   Wheeled and clattered away.

This is  from "Eddie's Service"  by Rudyard Kipling. 
https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/eddies_service.html

What does "the windows showed the day" mean?

I am glad if some one kindly taech me.

Comment: At a guess, it could simply mean that the dawning sun could be seen through the windows.

Answer (score 2):

> the windows showed the day

means that morning or daylight was shining through the windows

Remember, the service began at midnight

> Ordered a midnight service

so it seems the service lasted the entire night, during a storm

> Wicked weather for walking,
>   ...
>   The storm beat on at the windows,

Comment: Peter,thank you so much! I remember the service was  at midnight!---Hiroshi